# Is it possible to fold paragraphs in YAML, while preserving the newlines between paragraphs?

Tags: yaml

I have 3 paragraphs of text:

```yaml
my_value:
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc
    ullamcorper dolor nibh, ut vestibulum purus vestibulum eu. Nulla in
    elit sed ante maximus efficitur eu eget orci. Donec fermentum diam at
    ornare auctor. Aenean porttitor, est ac dignissim sagittis, ligula
    justo luctus risus, ac auctor turpis magna id ex.

    Nunc imperdiet dictum mi efficitur malesuada. Sed in ipsum imperdiet,
    aliquam massa vitae, vehicula nisl. Morbi eu odio imperdiet, auctor
    nulla in, convallis turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin id
    egestas massa. Maecenas finibus erat ac cursus auctor.

    Nullam elementum accumsan massa id finibus. Praesent ipsum lectus,
    venenatis nec congue vel, dignissim rutrum eros. Suspendisse potenti.
    Vivamus et sodales ipsum. Mauris eu erat luctus nibh posuere sodales
    in ut diam.
```

What I want as a result is a string that has 3 newlines - the 2 between the paragraphs, and the final newline. The newlines within each paragraph should be folder into spaces.

If I use `my_value: >`, every newline is folded, so the newlines between the 3 paragraphs are not preserved. If I use `my_value: |`, the newlines within each paragraph are preserved, which isn't what I want either.

Is there any way to represent this to get the right output, short of just having super long lines in my yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use `my_value: >`, every newline is folded

That's not true. Maybe you are using a broken YAML library?

`>` is the indicator for the "folded block scalar".

Empty lines in a folded block scalar are *not* folded.

So a plain scalar like you showed and a folded block scalar can be the same:

```
plain:
  a
  b

  c
folded block: >-
  a
  b

  c
double quoted: "a b\nc"
```

So you can use a plain scalar or a folded block scalar in your case.

(More about [Block Scalars](https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html#folded) in my article about quoting)

Comment: I was wrong. `>` wasn't folding the newlines between my paragraphs. What I didn't realize at first was that I have 2 `\n` characters between each paragraph. One to drop to the new line, and one to leave a blank line. `>` was turning those 2 `\n` characters into a single `\n` character, which in my output looked like one big paragraph, even though it did have newlines between them. Realizing that, I was able to fix the issue. Thanks tinita!